# Alertdialog setView() using existing xml widget

Tags: java, android

I have an EditText in a .xml file with LinearLayout and want to add it as the `setView()` parameter on an AlertDialog. Is this possible? Here's what I've tried:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
final EditText input = new EditText(this);
builder.setView(input);
```

But the dialog is blank when launched. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use it like this

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, null);
builder.setView(dialogView);

AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
alertDialog.show();
```

using `dialogView` you can get your `EditText` like this

```
EditText editText = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.your_edit_text);
```

Answer (score 0):

It might help

```
 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
   LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.YourLayout, null));
AlertDialog ad = builder.create();
```